# place objects in canvas where clicked using binding python

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, binding

I want to make an object appear in the tkinter window where the user clicks.
I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Storage:

    def __init__(self):
        x = None
        circle = None
        w=None

class Game:

    def Start():
        #make object appear where clicked

root = Tk()

w = Canvas(root, width=200, height=100)
w.pack()

w.bind("<Button-1>", Start)


start = Button(text="Start!", command=Game.Start)
start.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**first of all you should put the canvas object on the frame, then bind the canvas to the event requred**

```
from tkinter import *

class Storage:

    def __init__(self):
        x = None
        circle = None
        w=None

class Game:

    def Start(event):
        print("clicked at", event.x, event.y)
        x = event.x
        y = event.y
        w.create_rectangle(x, y, 100, 100, fill="blue")

root = Tk()




frame = Frame(root, width=200, height=200)

frame.pack()
w = Canvas(frame, width=200, height=100)
w.pack()
w.bind("<Button-1>", Game.Start)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Putting the canvas in a frame doesn't change anything. Why do you say a frame is necessary?